# XAML Namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml is not resolved

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express, working on a Silverlight 4 project in C#. This started happening all of a sudden in my project, I get the error that this XAML Namespace is not resolved:

```
XAML Namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml is not resolved
```

If it helps, here is the section of the XAML file in which the error is being raised:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:GetGlue="clr-namespace:GetGluePlugin;assembly=GetGluePlugin"
                xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:Seesmic.Sdp.Utils;assembly=Seesmic.Sdp.Utils">
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're seeing...

http://laumania.net/2010/06/21/a-possible-solution-to-the-error-xaml-namespace-httpschemas-microsoft-comexpressionblend2008-is-not-resolved/

... or this...

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/e180becd-5e59-4b1d-bd06-9a9547b4e68f

Both relate to Blend removing an attribute and breaking your XAML. It removes (or forgets to add) the mc:Ignorable="d" attribute to UserControls.

Comment: Correct link to Mads Laumann's post: http://laumania.net/2010/06/21/a-possible-solution-to-the-error-xaml-namespace-httpschemas-microsoft-comexpressionblend2008-is-not-resolved/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `WindowsBase` and `PresentationCore` assembly again:

```
<add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

<add assembly="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>"
```

For me this seems to resolve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I copied a Resource Dictionary file from another project.  I think that it must be a VS 2010 bug or something because it was cured by creating a new ResourceDictionary!  I then deleted the new Dictionary that I didn't need.