# silverlight error "XAML Namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml is not resolved"

Tags: silverlight

I'm a beginner in silverlight, I just copied a project and renamed the original namespace, but I got this error "XAML Namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml is not resolved", in different files like app.xaml, styles.xaml, MainPage.xaml, BusyIndicator.xaml.
I found there question about this error but the solution does not work with me.
[Here is the old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250198/xaml-namespace-http-schemas-microsoft-com-winfx-2006-xaml-is-not-resolved)

Comment: Do you get this error at run-time or design-time? (Or both?) Does the project itself build?

Comment: it is in design time, I could not build the project

Answer (score 2):

Multiple DLLs in Silverlight share the same URL-based namespace rather than use lots of traditional namespaces.

The likely cause of the error is that you are missing the underlying DLLs. Check the original project references of the project you copied and make sure you reference them all in the new project.

*I can also recommend using a trial of [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) as it adds an autocomplete style feature for Xaml reference (one of my favourite features).*